# Seating 4 people around circular table

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

Hello so I know that there is formula for seating people around table and it is: (n-1)! where n is number of people, but I don't understand how it really works
For Example when i seat 4 people around circular table and I use the formula i get that there are 6 possibilites

But when i try to picture them i only get those, how can i draw 3 left possibilities?
[image]

Comment: This is missing some cases. For example, (clockwise from top left), C A B D.

Comment: It depends which symmetries you allow - if you count clockwise and counterclockwise versions of an same arrangement as the same you halve the number of possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every drawing you can swap C and D.

Comment: Ok i swapped C and D and there is a picture on imgur https://imgur.com/jZCQa25. Shouldn't we count them as 1 possiblity because each person has the same person next to them

Answer (score 1):

You'll also count the anticlockwise case for each of the 3 possibilities because that is how you find distinct arrangements for a circular setting. i.e. you'll consider clockwise and anticlockwise as separate possibilities, which is trivial. Hope this helps.